# assertJson only looks at the first list within repsonse. (PHP,Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel

Greeting,

I am trying to produce this test to test my schools API

```
        $suburb = "BobsTown";
        $postcode = 2000;
        $response = $this->json('GET',"http://hostname/api/schools/$postcode/$suburb");

        $response->
            assertStatus(200)->
                assertJson([[
                    ["school_name" => "BobsTown High School",
                    "school_type" => "Secondary"
                    ],
                        [[
                            "boys-enrolments" => "439",
                            "girls-enrolments" => "381",
                            "indigenous-enrolments" => "12"
                        ]]
                ]]
            );
```

The actual repose of the API is as follows.

```
{
   {
    {
        {
            "calendar_year": "2019",
            "school_name": "BobsTown Public School",
            "suburb": "BobsTown",
            "postcode": 2000,
            "school_type": "Primary",
        },
        {
            {
                "girls-enrolments": 318,
                "boys-enrolments": 359,
                "indigenous-enrolments": 16,
            }
        }
    },
    {
        {
            "calendar_year": "2019",
            "school_name": "BobsTown Valley Public School",
            "suburb": "BobsTown",
            "postcode": 2000,
            "school_type": "Primary",
        },
        {
            {

                "girls-enrolments": 281,
                "boys-enrolments": 269,
                "indigenous-enrolments": 12,
            }
        }
    },
    {
      {
            "calendar_year": "2019",
            "school_name": "BobsTown High School",
            "suburb": "BobsTown",
            "postcode": 2000,
            "school_type": "Secondary",
      },
      {
            {
               "girls-enrolments": 381,
               "boys-enrolments": 439,
               "indigenous-enrolments": 12,
            }
      }
    }
   }
```

This test code works correctly when the school being tested is the first in the list however, as you can see BobsTown High School is the last in the list, the test only seems to check the first item in the list.

phpunit returns this error.

```
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
...
-      'school_name' => 'BobsTown High School',
+      'school_name' => 'BobsTown Public School',
...
```

I am using assertJson incorrectly? My assumption was it returns true is the assertion is true anywhere in the response.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the functionality I wanted using `assertJsonFragment()`

```php
  public function testSchools4()
    {
        $suburb = "BobsTown";
        $postcode = 2000;
        $response = $this->json('GET', "http://hostname/api/schools/$postcode/$suburb");

        $response->assertStatus(200)->assertJsonFragment(
            [
                "school_name" => "BobsTown High School",
                "school_type" => "Secondary"
            ]
        )->assertJsonFragment([
            "girls-enrolments" => 381,
            "boys-enrolments" => 439,
            "indigenous-enrolments" => 12
            ]);
    }
}
```